# Why some Errors return while building apk (in Android Studio) although app works?

Tags: android, android-studio

I get Errors While building apk although App works fine !

I followed Errs and Fixed all Bugs, but wondering why that happened although app works? What is the difference between source-code and apk ?

Comment: what kind of errors are you facing while generating apk?

Comment: alots of errors still working with them .. some inner classes must be public and static and modify constrators of some class . example Error:Error: Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead [ValidFragment]

Comment: Are you using another source code? or you make it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How Source code run in a device? You have to make it compatible for the device where you are going to run. What error you have seen ?

**APK:**
APK is a generated Package file which is also called "**Android application package (APK)** The package is file format used by the Android operating system for distribution and installation of application software and middle ware. More [here](http://Android%20application%20package%20(APK)%20is%20the%20package%20file%20format%20used%20by%20the%20Android%20operating%20system%20for%20distribution%20and%20installation%20of%20application%20software%20and%20middleware.)

**Source Code**

Source code and object code refer to the "before" and "after" versions of a computer program that is compiled before it is ready to run in a computer. The source code consists of the programming statements that are created by a programmer with a text editor or a visual programming tool and then saved in a file. For example, a programmer using the C language types in a desired sequence of C language statements using a text editor and then saves them as a named file. This file is said to contain the source code. It is now ready to be compiled with a C compiler and the resulting output, the compiled file, is often referred to as object code. The object code file contains a sequence of instructions that the processor can understand but that is difficult for a human to read or modify. For this reason and because even debugged programs often need some later enhancement, the source code is the most permanent form of the program.

More here about [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code)